# GeoPandas save to shapefile issue: Unable to open EPSG support file

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, fiona, geopandas

When I try to use to_file() to write a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame to a shapefile I get the following error.

```
df3.to_file('~/Desktop/testout.shp', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile');
```

> ERROR:Fiona:OGR Error 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.
>   Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the
>   directory containing EPSG csv files.

I don't know what it's talking about and can't seem to find anything online. Pls help.

Comment: Is the GDAL package installed? If it is, you need to identify where the data files are (aka where is gcs.csv) and define an environment variable called GDAL_DATA that points at that directory.

Comment: some online [docs](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable) for the gdal_data variable mentioned by mkennedy. and another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444310/how-to-set-the-gdal-data-environment-variable-to-point-to-the-directory-containi) - that might be close to a duplicate.

Comment: This did the trick: (in the terminal) 
$ export GDAL_DATA=/usr/local/share/gdal

Comment: @SeanRGB are you using os x here?

Comment: @SeanRGB You should write the solution below and mark the question as answered.